# Telegram Bot: Add action to keyboard button to add text in the chat inputbox

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have added a Inlinekeyboard button as reply_markup to a chat message, and now as an on click action, i want to add a text in the input box, to make it easy for the user ( the text is part of the input to be given in the conversation).

All I could find is 'switch_inline_query_current_chat', which only supports inline queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do it directly at this time. :(

You need to send/edit a message which contains a `switch_to_inline_current_chat` button, and ask user to click it.

I hope you can make this suggestions to [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport), this would be useful for further developers!